# Django south and django-admin-tools conflict

Tags: django, django-south

In my project I have an app called 'menu'. Also I'm using django-admin-tools, it also has app 'menu'.
If I run:

```
manage.py schemamigration menu --initial
```

New migration file appears in admin_tools.menu.migration directory, and it contains all admin_tools.menu models and my project menu models.

I tried to use 'SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES' setting. If I set it up for app 'menu', than migration file appears in that directory and it also contains all my project menu models and all admin_tools menu models.

Answer (score 2):

If apps have the same name you're going to have more issues. This is just the tip of the iceberg. I recommend a **curative solution as soon as possible**, e.g. renaming your app 'menu' into 'project_menu' or even 'project_specific_menu'.